# Selenium Sendkeys contain <ul><li> tag into textarea

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, asp.net-core-2.1, .net-core-2.1

When I try to send string contain `<ul><li>` tag into textbox using Selenium ,new tab is opened and textarea fill by `<ul>` only not `<li>`

For example:

```
var body = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"cke_1_contents\"]/textarea")); // then you find the body
body.SendKeys('<ul><li>option1</li><li>option2</li></ul>')
```

and then textarea fill by `<ul></ul>` and 2 new tab are opened in Chorome!!!

A true result : fill textarea by `<ul><li>option1</li><li>option2</li></ul>`

but now for each li opened new tab in browser and not put in textarea

Comment: why opne new tab in browser and why li is not in textarea?

Comment: tag your binding language

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by copying the string to clipboard and then past it with WebDriver SendKeys().
Like this:

```
Clipboard.SetText(myStringContainingHTML);
driver.FindElement(By.Id("myTxtBoxId")).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.LeftControl + "v");
```

In your specific question it will be

```
Clipboard.SetText("<ul><li>option1</li><li>option2</li></ul>");
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"cke_1_contents\"]/textarea")).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.LeftControl + "v");
```

Comment: Thanks a good way , but i used .Netcore and Clipboard not supported!

Comment: Try using Actions instead of driver.sendkeys(). Possibly this will work

Comment: I use action but again new tab opened and list tag not import to textbox.